# How to escape "\" in mule 4?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a function which replaces special characters, but i'm not being able to skip the backslash `\`. I tried to add `{ searchValue: "\", replaceValue: "\\" }`  to the searchReplace variable, but it doesn't work.

Below is the function:

````
%dw 2.0
output application/java

var searchReplace = [
        {
            searchValue: "?",
            replaceValue: "\?"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "&",
            replaceValue: "\&"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "|",
            replaceValue: "\|"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "!",
            replaceValue: "\!"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "^",
            replaceValue: "\^"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "~",
            replaceValue: "\~"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "*",
            replaceValue: "\*"
        },
        {
            searchValue: ":",
            replaceValue: "\:"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "+",
            replaceValue: "\+"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "'",
            replaceValue: "\'"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "-",
            replaceValue: "\-"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "{",
            replaceValue: "\{"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "}",
            replaceValue: "\}"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "[",
            replaceValue: "\["
        },
        {
            searchValue: "]",
            replaceValue: "\]"
        },
        {
            searchValue: "(",
            replaceValue: "\("
        },
        {
            searchValue: ")",
            replaceValue: "\)"
        }
]
fun replaceValuesArray(n,text,values) =
if (n == 0) text replace values[n].searchValue with(values[n].replaceValue) else replaceValuesArray(n - 1, text replace values[n].searchValue with(values[n].replaceValue), values)
var searchTerm = replaceValuesArray(sizeOf(searchReplace) - 1,payload.search, searchReplace)
---
if ((searchTerm == "") or (searchTerm == null)) "" else (searchTerm ++ "*")```
````

Comment: Why do you need to escape those characters in a Java string output? Also provide an example input and expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to escape some characters in an input string by adding a backslash character before them. This can be easily done with the `mapString()` function in DataWeave 2.4. Since the escaping is always the same we don't need a mapping table. A simple list of special characters to escape is enough.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var specialCharacters=["?", "&", "|", "[", "]", "\\"] // add characters as needed
---
payload dw::core::Strings::mapString 
    (if (specialCharacters contains ($)) "\\"++$ else $)
```

Input JSON (note that JSON requires the input backslash to be escaped):

```json
"this is \\a [test]"
```

Output Java String:

```
this is \\a \[test\]
```

The `mapString()` solution makes it very clear what is the intention of the expression. However if you are using an older version of DataWeave 2 you can get the same result by replacing the use of `mapString()` for splitting the string into an array of characters, use `map()` to transform, then join the output array of characters into a string again:

```js
payload splitBy "" map (if (specialCharacters contains ($)) "\\"++$ else $) joinBy ""
```

Comment: Thanks Aled! I see this way is much more convenient. You're the best!